# elegant way to convert date

Tags: python, django

working with django, I ve got the following form

```
class ReportDataForm(forms.Form):
start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
end_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

My date Fields have the following format: "mm/dd/yy" which matches one of the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS

Those datetime fields are submitted via a GET request and are used for a query.
Right now, my view looks ugly:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ReportDataForm(request.GET)
    context={'form':form}
    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = datetime.strptime("%m/%d/%y")
        end_date = datetime.strptime("%m/%d/%y")
        report = Mymodel.objects.filter(date__gte=start_date)\
                                .filter(date__lte=end_date)
```

Is there any way to avoid this conversion or to do it somewhere in the validator, since it has nothing to do with the view logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already being done for you. Just access `form.cleaned_data['start_date']` etc.